# Access Violation Exception in OpenCL Program

Tags: c, visual-c++, opencl, gpgpu

I get an Access Violation Exception in this line,

```
err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
```

What can i do for prevent this exception.
I am using AMD App SDK 3.0. My PC configurations are core i7 5500U CPU and AMD R5 M230 GPU, Windows 10 64-bit.

**My full program is here.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<CL/cl.h>

int main(void){
 cl_int err;
 cl_uint numPlatforms;

 err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
 if (CL_SUCCESS == err)
    printf("\nDetected OpenCL platforms: %d", numPlatforms);
 else
    printf("\nError calling clGetPlatformIDs. Error code: %d", err);

 return 0;
}
```

**Debugger Output:**

```
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Artista\Documents\Visual Studio 
2017\Projects\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot 
find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\IntelOpenCL64.dll'. Cannot 
find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common 
Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\intelocl64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB 
file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common 
Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\task_executor64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB 
file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common 
Files\Intel\OpenCL\bin\x64\cpu_device64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB 
file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdrcl64.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. 
Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 
'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository
\c0313248.inf_amd64_aad49543f8f7
14a1\amdhdl64.dll'.Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 
'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository
\c0313248.inf_amd64_aad49543f8f714a1\amdhdl64.dll'
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdfcl64.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdmcl64.dll'. Cannot findor 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dbghelp.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdbcl64.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdusc64.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 
'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository
\c0313248.inf_amd64_aad49543f8f714a1\amdocl64.dll'. Cannot find or open the 
PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\atiadlxx.dll'. Cannot find
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot 
find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot 
find or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\propsys.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wtsapi32.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find 
or open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'Test.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or 
open the PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 
'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository
\c0313248.inf_amd64_aad49543f8f714a1\atig6txx.dll'. Cannot find or open the 
PDB file.
'Test.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP 
SDK\3.0\bin\x86_64\amdocl12cl64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x000001896545F8E0 in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation executing location 0x000001896545F8E0.
```

> Exception : Exception thrown at 0x0000024AD73CF9F0 in opencl.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000024AD73CF9F0.

[Screenshot of the Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPrBg.jpg)

Comment: Looks like C. Why the C++ tag?

Comment: is it windows/linux enviroment? 32-bit or 64-bit OS?

Comment: @MahmoudFayez I'm using windows environment 64-bit

Comment: @AndersK. I tried the solution but still getting the same exception. i will attach the debugger output here

Comment: You need to make sure that you installed the 64-bit version of the SDK and you are linking against it. if you are using dynamic link then make sure they are matched. I am guessing that you are mixing 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs and EXEs

Comment: Have you tried running your app without attaching a debugger?

Comment: @MahmoudFayez I'm using x64 as active solution platform and i also linked the library folder that named X86_64. Is there any other things i should consider about?

Comment: @MohammedBakrSikal yes. console pops up and it crashed. (Display message "Test.exe has stopped working")